# How can i pass a variable into a string to be used as part of a non-file commandline parameter?

Tags: bash, cygwin

The commandline command i want to run is an mkvmerge command:

```
mkvmerge arguments: [-o] [output_filename] [-a] [tracknumer] [-S] [source_filename]
```

So i have a variable `command` and it takes on the values of either `-a 1`, `-a 1 -S`, or `-S` depending on certain conditions being met, so i have this if statement in my bash script to run the command

```
if [[ ! -z $command ]]; then
    mkvmerge -o "${file}"$command "$sourcefile"
fi
```

The reason i have `$command` right next to `${file}` without a space is because `$command` contains a single leading whitespace. The issue that i'm having is that when i run the script, it is assuming $command to be part of the filename and not as additional parameters that are meant to follow after the filename.

Comment: Two spaces are also a valid separator, so you can try `"${file}" $command`...

Comment: That indicates there *isn't* a leading space in the variable. Try printing it with `printf '"%s"\n "$command"`.